# .....went to the village (to help/for helping?) the farmers

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Last summer the student went to the village ______ the farmers.

A) to help
B) for helping

Although both of the above options sound correct which one is a better choice to use here ? Or they both are equally good and don't make any difference ?

Comment: Follow your instinct! Mine says 'to help!'

Comment: I wouldn't trust "sounds correct" when learning a language. Could you add some grammatical explanation why one or the other might be correct?

Answer (score 1):

- Last summer the student went to the village ______ the farmers.

  1. **to help** - this means that the student went to the village in order to help the farmers.
  2. **for helping** - this means that going to the village was some kind of reward or punishment the student got for helping the farmers.